# "undefined reference" error with g++

Tags: c++, class, g++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I just wrote a simple game (if you're interested, each player should say a word beginning with the last letter of the word said by his opponent.) 
It won't compile with the following output:

```
totosus@btop:~/projects/dict$ g++ wordgame.cc 
/tmp/ccIjadX8.o: In function `main':
wordgame.cc:(.text+0x90b): undefined reference to `WGdict::~WGdict()'
wordgame.cc:(.text+0x92e): undefined reference to `WGdict::~WGdict()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code:

dict.h:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

#define ft first
#define sd second
#define MCMSB map<char,map<string,bool> >
#define MSB map<string,bool>
#define PSB pair<string,bool>

using std::map;
using std::vector;
using std::pair;
using std::set;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::string;



class WGdict{
    private:

    MCMSB M;//main map
    bool HasBeenFilled;

    bool WasUsed(MSB::iterator it){//a small function which checks the "used" bit at the iterator
    return (*it).sd;
    }

string strip(string str){
    string::iterator i = str.begin();
    char space = ' ';
    while( *i == space){
        i = str.erase(str.begin());
    }
    i = str.end()-1;
    while( *i == space){
        str.erase(i);
        i = str.end()-1;
    }
    return str;
}

bool  FillFromFile(string filename){return FillFromFile(filename,false);}//default

bool  FillFromFile(string filename, bool PreserveContents){//fills the main map with contents of file
    ifstream dicfile ( filename.c_str() );//open file
    if(dicfile.is_open()&&dicfile.good()){
        string str;
        if(!PreserveContents){
            M.clear();//clear map
        }
        char c;
        while(!dicfile.eof()){//get words from file and add them to the map
            dicfile>>str;
            str = strip(str);
            c=str[0];
            M[c].insert(PSB(str,false));
        }
        HasBeenFilled = 1;
        dicfile.close();
        return true;
    }
    else if (dicfile.is_open()) dicfile.close();
    return false;
}

bool setbool(string word, bool state , bool flip){// set to STATE (or flip) the "used" bool
    bool ok = false;
    MCMSB::iterator it = M.find(word[0]);
    if( it != M.end() ){
        MSB::iterator O = it->sd.find(word);
        if( O != it->sd.end()){
            if(!flip) O->sd = state;
            else  O->sd = ! (O->sd);
            ok=true;
        }
    }
}

public:


WGdict(){HasBeenFilled = false;}//default constructor

~WGdict(){ M.clear(); }//destructor

WGdict(string fname){//file-opening constructor
    open(fname);
}

bool open(string fname){//open new file with default settings
    return FillFromFile(fname);
}

bool open(string fname,bool pc){//open new file and choose whether to preserve contents
    return FillFromFile(fname,pc);
}

MSB find(char ch){//search the dictionary by first letter
    MCMSB::iterator it = M.find(ch);
    MSB results;
    if (it!=M.end()){
        results = (*it).sd;
    }
    return results;
}

vector<string> find(char ch, bool wu){//search the dictionary by first letter&"used" parameter
    vector<string> v;
    MSB search = find(ch);
    for(MSB::iterator it = search.begin();it!=search.end();it++){
        if(WasUsed(it)==wu) v.push_back((*it).ft);
    }
}

set<string> findS(char ch, bool wu){//same as previous, but output is in a set
    set<string> s;
    MSB search = find(ch);
    for(MSB::iterator it = search.begin();it!=search.end();it++){
        if(WasUsed(it)==wu) s.insert((*it).ft);
    }
}

void save(string filename){//save a dictionary
    ofstream of( filename.c_str() );
    if(of.is_open()&&of.good()){
        for(MCMSB::iterator me=M.begin() ; me!=M.end();me++){
            for(MSB::iterator i = me->sd.begin(); i != me->sd.end() ; i++){
                of<<( (*i).ft+"\n" ).c_str();
            }
        }
        of.close();
    }
    else if (of.is_open()) of.close();
}

void add(string word){add(word,false);}//add a word to the dictionary

void add(string word,bool b){
    char c = strip(word)[0];
    M[c].insert(PSB(word,b));
}

bool flip(string word){return setbool(word,0,1);}

bool use(string word){return setbool(word,1,0);}

bool use(string word, bool state){ return setbool(word,state,false);}

bool exists(string word){
    bool ok = false;
    MCMSB::iterator it = M.find(word[0]);
    if( it != M.end() ){
        MSB::iterator O = it->sd.find(word);
        if( O != it->sd.end()){
            ok=true;
        }
    }
}

bool used(string word){
    if(exists(word)){
        return M.find(word[0])->sd.find(word)->sd;
    }
    return true;
    }
};
```

wordgame.cc:

```
# include "dict.h"
# include <vector>
# include <iostream>
# include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

char getlastletter(string str){return str[str.size()-1];}

char sayword(vector<string> words){
random_shuffle ( words.begin(), words.end() );
string theword = (*words.begin());
cout<<theword;
return getlastletter(theword);  
}

char big(char ch){
if('a'<=ch<='z')  ch-=32;
return ch;
}

char small(char ch){
if('A'<=ch<='Z')  ch+=32;
return ch;
}

string small(string str){
for(string::iterator it = str.begin();it != str.end();it++){
    (*it) = small((*it));
}
}

string big(string str){
for(string::iterator it = str.begin();it != str.end();it++){
    (*it) = big((*it));
}
}


int main(){
    WGdict dict;
vector<string> ws;
string fnm,word;
char yourletter = 'a';
char myletter;

while(true){
    cout<<"Write the filename of the dictionary:";
    cin>>fnm;
    if(fnm == "[exit]" || dict.open(fnm)) break;
    else cout<<"It seems that the file \""<<fnm<<"\" does not exist.\n Try again\n\n" ;
}
if(fnm == "[exit]") return 0;
cout<<"Let's play a word game!\n\n";


while(true){
    cout<<"My turn: ";
    ws = dict.find(yourletter,false);
    if(ws.size() == 0){//exit if no more words are available.
        cout<<"uh oh. It appears that I couldn't find any unused words with this letter. \n But, yet, congratulations! You won! \n bye! \n";
        return 0;
    }
    myletter = sayword(ws);
    cout<<"\n";
    ws = dict.find(myletter,false);
    if(ws.size() ==                          0){//exit if no more words are available.
        cout<<"So... I managed to win this game! My dictionary contains no more words beginning with this letter. \n Although I won, you also did well.  \n bye! \n See you soon!";
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<"Your turn:\n";
    while(true){
        cout<<big(myletter);
        cin>>word;
        word = small(word);
        if (word == "[exit]") return 0;
        if ( word[0] == small(myletter) ){
            if(dict.exists(word)) {
                if(!dict.used(word)){
                    yourletter = getlastletter(word);
                    dict.use(word);
                    break;
                }
                else cout<<"this word has already been used \n";
            }
            else cout<<"Sorry, I couldn't find \""<<word<<"\" in my dictionary. \n";
        }else cout<<"\""<<word<<"\" does not begin with letter "<<big(myletter)<<"! \n";
        cout<<"try again! \n";
    }
}   
}
```

I couldn't understand neither what is causing the error nor how to fix it, so please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: why does it not work for me, then?

Comment: Arrrgh, please PLEASE delete those `#define`s from the header file! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the compilation/object files in your directory and recompile - the code works great, you probably just need a make-clean.

Comment: Thanks! It did compile. But now the program crashes with "segmentation fault". Going to find out what that means.

Comment: No problem, sometimes that happens.  It gets worse when you get big apps and start using linked libraries with big make files :p

Comment: The error comes out right after the "Let's play a word game!\n"; statement, even though i wrote another output line right after it.

Comment: Make another question for it, but just for a quick pointer: cout is buffered (held until printing to screen is favorable), cerr isn't (it goes directly to screen right when you use it).  If you switch your couts to cerrs you might see the next line of output before the program dies.

Comment: Ironically, I found this answer about 5 minutes after I just spent two hours figuring it out myself. :(